# Homeowner's insurance and alleged business misconduct

Tags: united-states, small-business, home-insurance

In the US homeowner's insurance usually also covers liability for unintentional acts, such as knocking over a vase in someone else's home. Suppose someone is accused of an act that would be a business activity if the accusation is true, but the homeowner claims the act never happened. For example, a notary who in reality does not charge for notarizations is accused of failing to check the ID of someone who turned out to be an imposter, but the notary claims to have had nothing to do with the purported notarization.

Would the notary's homeowner's insurance cover the notary's defense costs?

Comment: Check the policy details is the only general answer here. Insurance is regulated at the state level, so policies vary.

Comment: Just to clarify: you are a notary, but you didn't purchase Errors & Omission insurance to cover your notarization activities. Is that correct? What about a bond?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep yes, the hypothetical notary didn't purchase Errors & Ommissions, feeling that the occasional free notarization wasn't enough of a risk to warrant it. And the hypothetical notary lives in a state where no bond is required.

Comment: The scenario could be pretty much any occupation; maybe the homeowner is accused of providing inadequate carpentry for a fee but the homeowner claims to have never done, or charged for, any carpentry outside her own home.

Comment: Don't these policies usually provide liability only for injuries and property damage? It seems unlikely that a homeowner's policy would pay for legal fees related to a home business.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep A bond wouldn't help. A bond would pay the member of the public who was wronged, but then they would be entitled to recover/sue the principal (notary) for the amount they paid out. A bond protects the public when you are self-insured.

Comment: @barbecue home (or renter's) insurance in Canada (and at least parts of the US, I understand?) tends to include some amount of personal/premises liability insurance. They still won't cover a home business, but I think that is OP's question, does the liability coverage kick in if you are "accused" of (but deny) doing the business.

Comment: @mbrig In the US, homeowners insurance often does include some coverage of home businesses, but usually limited to damages and injuries occurring in or on the covered property. Whether or not someone notarized a document doesn't seem like it would involve damage or injury in the house. The notarization could be done in a coffee shop, would we expect the coffee shop to be liable? If your neighbor accuses you of stealing their lawnmower, would you expect homeowners insurance to pay for your legal defense?

Comment: @barbecue Incorrect. Homeowner's liability is broad. This is actually very confusing, see a lawyer/licensed insurance agent to interpret your specific coverage, but in this [hypothetical policy](https://www.iii.org/sites/default/files/docs/pdf/HO3_sample.pdf) liability (coverage E, page 16) is not contingent on the damage occurring at home. Vehicular (car, boat, plane, hovercraft) liability is disclaimed, which further supports this. Relevant to the OP, Section II, E.2 disclaims business liability.

Comment: @user71659 You seem to have misread my comment. I'm saying homeowners insurance does not, as a rule, pay for legal fees related to a business dispute with a customer simply because your business is run from your home. The link you provided doesn't address that at all, and specifically refers to bodily injury and property damage. I'm not talking about someone hurting themselves with your chainsaw, I'm talking about someone suing you for failing to fulfill a business obligation. If you get sued for trademark infringement by a customer, your homeowner's policy won't pay your attorney's fees.

Comment: @user71659 perhaps you were confused by my usage of the words "covered property" which does not mean house, but any and all property which is covered by the policy, regardless of whether it is located at the house.

Comment: @barbecue No, your last scenario undermines your position. If you unintentionally/non-criminally destroy your neighbor's lawnmower on their property, you would likely be covered by your homeowner's liability policy, even though it doesn't involve your home. The idea of bundling liability is to protect you (and lienholders) from _losing_ your home in a lawsuit, and that has to cover acts outside of home.

Comment: @user71659 We seem to be having a real problem communicating. I never said if you destroy your neighbor's lawnmower. What I said was, you are ACCUSED of stealing your neighbor's lawnmower, and are in court for said theft. You hire a defense attorney. Is your homeowner's insurance going to pay that attorney simply because the neighbor claims his lawnmower is in your garage? No, obviously not.

Comment: @user71659 Again, the point, the ONLY point I'm making, is that homeowner's insurance, in general, unless specific riders are attached, will cover property damage and personal injury, but will not pay for legal expenses related to a business dispute with a customer simply because the business happened to be based in the home. The idea that such coverage would be standard is crazy, and I'd be extremely surprised if you can find an example.

Comment: @user71659 Again, you've misunderstood me. At no time did I ever claim that homeowner's insurance will not cover events happening outside the home. You keep repeating that, but it's not what I wrote.

Comment: @barbecue Nope. I keep pointing out your lawnmower scenario is faulty and you keep diverting my words into a business. I said business use is generally excluded. However, breaking somebody's lawnmower, or vase, outside excluded business, is included. Yes, the insurance would pay to defend you against the lawnmower/vase civil liability lawsuit if they felt it was better than settling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149467/discussion-between-barbecue-and-user71659).

Comment: Why would anyone expect homeowner's insurance to take the least interest in any business action?

Either way, if your notary does not charge for notarizations then either you left out significant details or no contract exists between the notary and anyone else.

Then, is your notary accused of something criminal, something unethical that might lead to being struck off, or what?

Answer (score 4):

The thing with the law is that often the correct answer to any such question is "it depends".  This question would certainly qualify.

In many situations the answer would be "yes".  In many cases the goal of homeowners insurance is to protect the mortgage holder from loss which is why it is required and powerful.  Luckily the same provisions hold true if one pays off the mortgage.

Basically if the defendant's personal assets are at risk, then yes the homeowners insurance will provide protection.  When one seeks to increase their liability protection by buying an umbrella policy, then one must first max out their liability coverage on their auto and home insurance.

It may not cover in situations where the home is owned in a trust or some other legal shelter, or if the notary has a properly setup LLC.  But in those cases it is unlikely the plaintiff could attach the home anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The notary would need to read the policy very carefully. Generally personal liability policies (both homeowners and umbrella) exclude professional liability. For the situation described an E&O liability coverage would have been more suitable.

This is something the notary would probably want to get a lawyer involved in sooner rather than later. In addition to the monetary damages, there's a risk of the State coming after the notary if the alleged act is not proven to have been fabricated.

Comment: Right, but part of the dispute at hand is over whether this _was in fact_ a professional activity -- homeowner claiming that it was done purely free-of-charge.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't think the fact that they didn't receive payment matters when doing professional work requiring licensing.

Comment: The point of the question is that, according to the homeowner, the homeowner was not performing a professional activity because either the activity never happened at all, or the homeowner was not involved in it at all.

Comment: @GerardAshton not sure what's the point of your comments. As I said - they'll need to read the policy to check what's covered, and contact the insurance company for clarifications. Most likely this would not be covered because it is a professional/business activity. If they have a professional license they should carry a professional liability or E&O coverage that would take care of this.  It may be that their personal policy is permissive enough to cover that, but we wouldn't know because we don't have it in front of us. They do.

Comment: @littleadv Can coverage depend on unproven statements by the adversary? If the adversary says business was going on it's not covered but if the adversary says social activity it's covered?

Comment: @GerardAshton you should talk to a lawyer. You seem to be seeking some validation here, but it's not productive